# How to Use the TFS SDK to Determine If a Checked Out File Has Changed

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have a tool that generates C# files.  I've been able to programmatically checkout the file
using this method:

```
private static void CheckoutFile(string fileName)
{
    var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(fileName);
    var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);
    var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);

    workspace.PendEdit(fileName);
}
```

But after the file has been generated I want to determine if there has been any changes to the file, and if not, to undo the check out.  How do I do that with the TFS SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, the TFS clients (`tfpt uu`, for example) determine whether you've changed a checked-out file by comparing the hash of the local file against the hash of the server item at the version that you have in your workspace.

To implement this behavior:

1. Compute the MD5 hash of the local file
2. Query the item on the server: [`workspace.VersionControlServer.GetItems(fileName, new WorkspaceVersionSpec(workspace), RecursionType.None)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138911.aspx)
3. Compare the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item.aspx)'s [`HashValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item.hashvalue.aspx) with the value computed in step 1.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  The Undo operation was very time intensive so I have instead opted to create a temp file, and only checkout the file if it has actually changed.